# What are the Apache Proxy settings for Blazor Server?

Tags: apache, websocket, blazor, proxypass

I'm attempting to deploy Blazor Server on a Ubuntu / Apache system. Sucker for punishment, I know. The only part not working is WebSockets, and I suspect it's down to my proxy configuration. My knowledge of Apache ProxyPass rules is pretty sketchy; mostly I've copied similar examples from elsewhere. I've previously successfully installed R/Shiny behind this proxy, and WebSockets were a key part of that. Blazor seems to have some different config including that _blazor suffix.

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

```
        <IfModule rewrite_module>
                RewriteEngine on
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}     =websocket
                RewriteRule /ProjectName/(.*)               ws://localhost:5001/$1 [P,L]
                RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade}     !=websocket
                RewriteRule /ProjectName/(.*)               https://localhost:5001/$1 [P,L]
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule proxy_http_module>
                SSLEngine on
                SSLProxyEngine on
                ProxyPreserveHost on
                ProxyRequests off
                ProxyPass /ProjectName/ https://localhost:5001/
                ProxyPassReverse /ProjectName/ https://localhost:5001/
                ProxyPassMatch ^/ProjectName/_blazor/(.*) https://localhost:5001/_blazor/$1
                ProxyPass /ProjectName/_blazor ws://localhost:5001/_blazor
                ProxyPassReverse /ProjectName/ ws://localhost:5001/
        </IfModule>
```

Here is the error output in the browser console:

> Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to https://my.domain.com/ProjectName/_blazor'.
>
> blazor.server.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.domain.com/ProjectName/_blazor?id=P34U8sn41b71opA0lM-xsA' failed
>
> Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the transport.
>
> Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
>
> Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.